# mysql_query(...) returns boolean value

Tags: php, mysql

My PHP snippet does not work, `var_dump(..)` says `bool(false)` but the db is filled with 1 record. What am I doing wrong?

```
$sessionResultSet = mysql_query('select * from sessions');
```

Comment: One line of code just doesn't cut it. It's like trying to find a black golf ball on the 18th hole at midnight (with no moon anywhere to be found), after drinking rum & coke for all the other 17. *hic!*

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). You will also want to [Prevent SQL Injection!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Care to join me for a session of rum & coke? We'll need to find someone to drive the golf cart though.

Comment: I'm in. My clubs are even cleaned up and ready to go.

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_query`return false if you have an error in your SQL query.

`echo mysql_error();`

should fix that problem.

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). We need to stop reinforcing bad habits.

Comment: I got a message called "No database selected" but why? after i called mysql_connect i selected my db with "mysql_select_db(...)"?

Comment: @GeorgeKrause Is this new code? If so, you're making a mess of things by trying to get it working with this antiquated interface.